# domain driven design depends on static methods?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

I have been reading a lot online/offline about where to put validation and business rules in general for domain driven design. What I could not understand is how can an entity provides methods that does validation and business rules without resorting to static methods or having a service? This is especially important for cases where the domain object does not need to be instantiate yet, but we need to validate a value that will eventually used to set the object's attribute.

I noticed blog postings such as http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2007/10/24/entity-validation-with-visitors-and-extension-methods/ relies on .NET's specific extension method, which is not available in programming languages such as Java. I personally don't like static methods are they cannot be overridden and hard to test.

Is there anyway I could do this without static methods or having to instantiate an unnecessary domain object just to use its validation and business rules methods. If not, does that mean domain driven design is very dependent on static methods?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post an example or two?

Comment: Let's just take an example of a website registration.

Comment: Let's just take an example of an e-commerce website registration. If registering a customer required the customer to specify a username for the website account. The customer will be notified by emails if the registration is successful (member details needs to be reviewed along with other information provided during the registration steps) Since according to DDD, the Customer entity (represented by Customer class) must contain the method to validate username, how would this method be called if the Customer object is not created until the registration is reviewed?

Answer (score 2):

Use ValueObjects **Not** Entity.

In the registration case, a UserName value object could be introduced. Create a Username object when receiving the registration. Implement validation in the constructor of the UserName.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879421/domain-validation-in-a-cqrs-architecture) and this [presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Value-Objects-Dan-Bergh-Johnsson)  for more detail.

**Edit1:**
1.How to handle cases where different validation rules applied for different context. 
 For example: The username must not have numbers for certain type of members, but it is required for other types of members?

Maybe different factory methods could do that. like UserName.forGoldenCardMember(...) or UserName.forPlainMember(...). Or make MemberType （a hierachy maybe） to validate UserName.

Another alternative solution is use AggregateFactory（AccountFactory in this case）.

2.Is constructor the only place to put the validation code? I did read online about two points of view: an object must always be valid vs. not always. Both present good arguments, but any other approach?

I prefer valid approach personally. Passing an maybe invalid value object harms encapsulabilty.

**Edit2:**
Require
a) validation business rule based on context(different username rules for member types)
b) keep validating all business rules even if one of them fail

Stick with Single responsibility principle by using Value Object(MemberType this case).
AggregateFactory could be introduced to ease the application layer(coarser granularity).

```
class AccoutFactory {
    Account registerWith(Username username, MemberType type, ....) {
        List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
        errors.addAll(type.listErrorsWith(username));
        errors.add(//other error report...

        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(errors)) {
            return new Account(username,....);
        } else {
            throw new CannotRegisterAccountException(errors);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit3:** 
For questions in the comments
a) Shouldn't the Username object be the one that has a method that returns the error like 
the listErrorsWith()? After all, it is the username that has different rules for different member type?

We could check this question from another perspective: MemberTypes have different rules for username. This may replace if/else block in the Username.listErrosWith(String, MemeberType) with polymorphism;

b) If we have the method in the MemberType, the knowledge will not be encapsulated in the Username.Also, we are talking about making sure Username is always valid.

We could define the validity of Username without MemberType rules. Let’s say "hippoom@stackoverflow.com" is a valid username, it is a good candidate for GoldenCard member but not good for SilverCard member.

c)  I still can't see how performing validation that returns a list of errors without getting the list from exception thrown by the constructor or static method. Both does not look ideal IMHO.

Yes, the signature of listErrorsWith():List looks weired, I'd rather use validate(username) with no returning value(throw exception when fails). But this will force the cilent to catch every validation step to run validations all at once.

Comment: I read the answers to the question and watching the presentation. I can see why the Username object is introduced. However, few questions: <br /> 1. How to handle cases where different validation rules applied for different context. <br /> For example: The username must not have numbers for certain type of members, but it is required for other types of members? <br /> 2. Is constructor the only place to put the validation code? I did read online about two points of view: an object must always be valid vs. not always. Both present good arguments, but any other approach?

Comment: for 1) doesn't that mean the factory methods need to be static methods? I am not so fond of static methods as overriding and testing it is more difficult. I actually was thinking if we have to pass something like ChangeEmailCommand in the question you mentioned earlier to the constructor. It would also contain additional runtime parameters needed to validate the username beside the context name (e.g. member's type). However, somehow it feels weird to pass such object. This is one of the concerns I have when it comes to DDD vs service layer approach. Perhaps you enlighten me some more?

Comment: @user3054039 It doesn't have to be static method. An Aggregate factory is usually initiated first. But in my personal expierences, static methods for validation does little harm to testability.

Comment: Thank you your reply Hippoom...I am rather confused, how an Aggregate factory is related to the Value Object in this case? Is the factory expected to create the Username? another question came to mind is if we are going to validate in the constructor (always valid), how do you pass list of error(s) to the UI to be displayed (e.g. when trying to instantiate Registration application object)?

Comment: @user3054039 Updated answer. Domain layer is not responsible for Form validation(e.g. username length limit) by the way.

Comment: Shouldn't the Username object be the one that has a method that returns the error like the listErrorsWith()? After all, it is the username that has different rules for different member type? If we have the method in the MemberType, the knowledge will not be encapsulated in the Username.

Comment: Also, we are talking about making sure Username is always valid, not the Account, shouldn't this mean we need to have a factory that creates Username objects? If we have the factory that creates the Username objs, how can the factory use Username class to validate a username string is valid beside static methods and constructors?

Comment: Sorry if I am asking too many the questions. I still can't see how performing validation that returns a list of errors without getting the list from exception thrown by the constructor or static method. Both does not look ideal IMHO.

Comment: @user3054039 Not a problem, I enjoy the discussion, it helps me think deeper as well :)  see Edit3.

Comment: I can see your rationale on having the listError method in the MemberType. However, in my opinion having the listError somehow in the Username makes more sense and intuitive. Developers would look into Username class for anything related to Username first before MemberType. After all, it is about the Username validation, not MemberType.

Comment: I agree with avoiding the client to catch every validation steps. However, IMHO, calling listErrorWith() does not necessarily have to throw an exception. It could just return a boolean true for valid or false for not valid and List<Error> could be a parameter of listErrorWith() that will be populated if there is any error.

Comment: back to my earlier question: assuming Username is the place where to put the validation instead of MemberType. I honestly cannot see how we can avoid having the validation in the static method/constructor/having to instantiate the Username first and calling a non static validate() on the username String before calling Username.setValue() with the username String. What do you think?

Comment: BTW I agree having this discussion really help both of us improve our DDD skills! I do enjoy this discussion too!

Answer (score 1):

If you decided to use DDD in your application you need to build more complex solution. I agree with @Hippoom, you shouldn't use Entity for this purpose.

I would suggest this solution:

[DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) -> Service Layer (ValidationService -> Converter) -> Persistence Layer (Repository)

Some explanation:
When you received **DTO** from client side with all necessary parameters, you should validate it in you service layer (e.g. Use another service like **ValidationService**) which can throw exception if something wrong. If all Ok, you can create Entity from your **DTO** in **Converter** and persist it in **Repository**.

If you want flexible solution for ValidationService I'd suggest [Drools](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.0.Final/drools-docs/html/DroolsLanguageReferenceChapter.html)

Comment: I did read a lot about service layer vs domain objects (DDD). Conceptually, I agree with domain objects approach. However, it appears to me that the DDD requires more efforts to follow than using service layer approach. Both present strengths and weaknesses. I guess it is more on preferences of the developer teams that will determine which one to be adopted. What do you think?

Comment: @user3054039 Yes, it is completely up to you which approach should be chosen. I think, usage of service layer more convenient with huge application which should be flexible, provides common solution for set of problems and can be reconfigured without building new binaries.